# The log keeps recording "Http analyzer failed"?

Tags: php, laravel

Since few days ago, the laravel project I maintain started logging a lot of alert messages in the daily logging file (almost every second, like logs on each request). However, there's nothing I could find through the Internet, does anyone had the same problem before?

The message example is below:

```
production.ALERT: Http analyzer failed {"reason":"Maximum count of dump files reached. Recording stopped."}
```

Comment: You should have some third part library installed, AFAIR there is no Http analyzer in laravel code base. Take a look at your composer.json there should be an entry with an external package.

Comment: Have you tried searching the entire web application directory file contents for the error message?